# Use pytest skipif to check server's memory size

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to mark a pytest with `skipif` so it will not run it if the machine has less than X GB of memory. How can I do that?

Comment: What part do you have issue with?

Comment: How do I refer to the memory size in the decorator?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that check if you have enough memory and call it from `skipif`

```
import psutil

def check_enough_memory():
    minimum_memory = 2
    memory_size = psutil.virtual_memory().available >> 30
    return memory_size >= minimum_memory


@pytest.mark.skipif(not check_enough_memory(), reason='Not enough memory')
def test_something():
    ...
```

`check_enough_memory()` returns `True` if there is enough memory, so we invert it in the marker.

Comment: Nice usage of the binary shift operator!